# Best Car Recognition Algorithm

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Could anyone suggest the best algorithm for a real-time Car recognition (say in a parking space)?
I am planning to implement the same on FPGA as well. Kindly suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any pictures of the parking lot? This can make a big difference on your recognition method. My Initial guess though is having areas of interest marked (each parking stall) and then doing background subtraction

Comment: Currently planning on taking Satellite Images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean car *detection* or *recognition*?  Detection: where are all the cars?  Recognition: which car is this?  See: [Object detection versus object recognition](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/object-detection-versus-object-recognition)

In any case, the short form of the answer is to prototype the heck out of this, likely using OpenCV or libccv, your favorite neural network package, and as much horsepower as possible (several Nvidia GTX 980).  Don't worry about realtime-ness or implementation details, just get it working first.  The state of the art for object recognition and detection both is probably convolutional neural networks, check out stuff like AlexNet; there are simpler algorithms (eg Histogram of Oriented Gradient or HoG) which could do okay at detection, but not at recognition (there is a decent person detector using HoG, I think you can probably make a decent car detector in the same way).

Running this on a FPGA is... unlikely: high-end desktop GPUs are very well suited to the problem, and orders of magnitude faster at it.  People are working on neural network ASICs now, should be ready in a couple of years.

Comment: Recognition. For example, I want to count the number of cars of each model, i.e.:
Tesla - 2
Mercedes - 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try ISM : [Implicit shape models](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/courses/spring2007/395T/395T/papers/leibe_2004.pdf)

Comment: Okay. How about the others such as SIFT, SURF? Does it also help? Or is ISM more accurate or something?

Comment: Well, they could find a single, or a couple of objects. Finding a full set of database is more cumbersome. So in a way, yes ISM is more accurate. The code is also available:
https://code.google.com/p/object-detection-implicit-shape-model/source/browse/trunk/src/mImplicitShapeModel.cpp

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look and try it out. Thanks again.

Comment: And this is in OpenCV if I am not wrong!

Comment: @Krish Please read - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Citation - "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question."